# Не обновляется компонент после обновления store, что делать?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть вот такой блок кода в reducer, который может выполнится в любое время. В console.log выводится правильная структура обьекта updates(словарь), но компонент не перерисовывается(он присоединен к store) после повторного изменения store в этом куске кода. Правильно ли я меняю состояние в данном куске кода?

```
if (action.type === 'update_state') {
        let updates = state.updates || {};
        let machine = updates[action.machine_id];
        if (machine != null) {
            updates[action.machine_id] = {
                ...machine,
                state: action.state,
                date: action.date
            }
        } else {
            updates[action.machine_id] = {
                state: action.state,
                date: action.date
            }
        }
        console.log(updates);
        return {
            ...state,
            updates: updates
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение:

Использовать

```
return {
    ...state,
    updates: Object.assign({}, updates)
}
```

Но не понимаю, почему не сработало:

```
return {
   ...state,
   updates: updates
}
```

Comment: Не сработало, потому что объект updates остался тем же. Стейт должен быть иммутабельным. Менять содержимое объектов нельзя - а вы меняете.